# Im using Appium for Android Automation. Android app is closing while debugging the code.

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium

I have written the below code for opening an app and clicking on a link on the app. But when I am debugging the code then the android app is closing unexpectedly. When I am trying to verify the elements in the list in debug mode I saw my app getting closed on my mobile. Please find my code below:

```
File classRootPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classRootPath, "//Apps//");
        File app = new File(appDir, "base.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "XT1033");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.bt.bms");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.bt.bms.activities.MainTabActivity");

        AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(
                new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("tabText"));
        System.out.println(elements.size());
        System.out.println(elements.get(2).getText());
        elements.get(2).click();
        driver.closeApp();
    }
```

Comment: Use sleep() before the line driver.closeApp();

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it clicks very fast and you have `driver.closeApp();` right after that which makes it close very fast. Just put wait command after `click();` and it will work fine.